# Auctex silent compilation

Tags: auctex

When I compile a file with pdflatex from Auctex one of the buffers that I have opened shows the output of this operation. How to stop this behavior and keep the previously opened buffers?

Comment: Does the output log buffer open automatically?  What's the value of `TeX-show-compilation` variable (`C-h v TeX-show-compilation RET`)?  Is it non-nil?  If so, this is the culprit and this isn't the default value, you customized it in your init file.